# Short way of doing this in Excel. Transferring data to another sheet, then clearing cells and saving

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transfer data that is in one column (D4:D21 on sheet 'dispersed') to the next empty row in another sheet (B$:N$ on 'sheet4'). Also in the A column on sheet4, I want the date that is in 'dispersed'!b4 I then want the original cells cleared (so that it can be filled out again in a month) and the workbook saved.

I recorded a macro to do this but it is very long.  I also can't work out how to change it so that it fills the data on the next empty row as when I recorded the macro it lists the specific cells to paste to.

The end result in 'sheet4' should give me a running total of amounts paid.

Here is the macro that I recorded.

```
Sub Transfer_dispersments()
'
' Transfer_dispersments Macro
' Botton to transfer data from dispersment to totals
'

'
    Range("D4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D15").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Range("D4:D18").Select
    Range("D18").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Dispersed").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of determining the "last row" of a worksheet.  I used one method in the below code:

```
Sub Transfer_dispersments()
'
' Transfer_dispersments Macro
' Botton to transfer data from dispersment to totals
'
    Dim newRow As Long
    'Find last non-empty cell in column B
    '(and then add 1 so that we point to the row we want to write to)
    newRow = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Sheets("Sheet4").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Copy values from D4:D18 on Dispersed sheet
    '              to Bx:Px  on Sheet4 sheet
    Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(newRow, "B").Resize(1, 15).Value = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Dispersed").Range("D4:D18").Value)
    'Copy cell from B4 on Dispersed sheet
    '            to Ax on Sheet4 sheet
    Sheets("Dispersed").Range("B4").Copy Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(newRow, "A")

    'Clear contents of copied cells
    Sheets("Dispersed").Range("D4:D18").ClearContents
    Sheets("Dispersed").Range("B4").ClearContents

    'Save workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have been trying to get something to work for the last 6 hours and this works perfectly.